# Is Guilded Age's Gravedust meant to be a homage to Obi-Wan?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi, webcomics, guilded-age

[Note: Question contains spoilers for [Guilded Age](http://guildedage.net/)]

He is clearly *not* a [The Obi-Wan](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheObiWan), but consider these major similarities, among others:

> 1. They are both the last (or one of the last) members of a mystical/magical/hermit-like order [The Savasi Mystics and the Jedi] that wore plain brown robes, whose members (often) practiced sexual abstinence / lack of romantic attachment, and advocated peace, and could sense life forces.

.

> 2. Said order was annhilated by power-hungry folks who then assumed control of the society [Iver and Darths Sidious and Vader] and painted the murdered order as the one at fault, and many (some) of the order are hanging around on the Astral Plane / Force as glowy blue ghosts.

.

> 3. They were both personally murdered by said power-hungry folks (briefly, in case of Gravedust), who were at one point before turning villain, their good friends [Iver and Anakin]; both of them abandoned their bodies before being truly killed [Obi-Wan dissolving into the Force with the Whills' technique as Vader struck him down and Gravedust using his Runes to make for the Astral Plane as the poison started taking effect]; both then came back as previously mentioned glowy blue ghosts.

On a more personal note, they both seem to be the bearded older member of the party, with a fairly serious demeanor but a dry sense of darkish humor, who often try to restrain their more impulsive colleagues.

Given these similarities, is there any author/artist information about whether this was a deliberate homage on the creators' part?

Comment: Can I know why the downvotes? Aren't homages in webcomics a common phenomenon?

Comment: The only reason I can think of for the dowvotes is that the question is very jargony ("expy" isn't really a universally recognized word, not even on this site) and not very well structured (the title is necessary to understand the question, which feels forumy and doesn't meet common site norms).

Comment: "whose members (often) practiced sexual abstinence" - based on EU, Obi-Wan, out of all the Jedi, seems to not exactly fit...

Comment: @DVK It's lack of universality is the reason for the 'often'. It does seem to be highly recommended as per most EU sources. As for Obi-Wan, I haven't watched all of CW, but was Obi-Wan and Satine's relationship supposed to have been consummated? I thought they fell in love but refrained due to their duties (ditto with the Siri Tachi canon from the Jude Watson books). Also, thanks Avner!